# IdentityServer4 ProfileService is not being called for non Core clients

Tags: asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I have implemented IdentityServer4. I am facing issue authenticating users from **non Core Mvc** client as **IProfileService** not being called after login validation.
    When i try to login from **.NetCore Mvc** client its working fine.

```
Here is my Mvc.Net Client configurations  

app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
  {
                AuthenticationType = "oidc",
                SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",

                Authority = "http://localhost:5070/",
                RedirectUri = "http://localhost:65156/signin-oidc",

                ResponseType = "code id_token",
                ClientId = "Justt-IWA-001113",
                ClientSecret = "!Erty#@asd",
                Scope = "openid profile SavingsAPI",

            });
```

I need to issue user claims in ProfileService implementaion.Can anyone suggest some solution?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you call your IprofileService implementation in the

For instance if "ProfileService" is the implementation then

`AddIdentityServer()..AddProfileService<ProfileService>();`